# I need a formula that finds a departure date between two given dates where the departure occurs later than a given time

Tags: ms-access, expression, formula

Im using Access 365 2016.

I need a formula that finds a departure date between two given dates where the departure occurs later than a given time.

I have tried this formula but it doesnt work:

```
Between [date1] And [date2] Where (TimeValue([Date1] > 09:30
```

Thank you

The formula i quoted above is a simpler way of writing the formula that references controls on my form.

The formula below references controls in my Flights form and is the exact formula that I used in the expression builder.

```
Between [Forms]![Flights]![cboDeparture]

    And

    [Forms]![Flights]![cboDeparture2]

    And

    TimeValue([Forms]![Flights]![cboDeparture])>[Forms]![Flights]![cboGreaterThanTime])
```

I altered the formula according to the code provided by Gustav in the comments section but neither code worked. See comments.
This is the code that I used for **Method 1:**

```
    (Between [Forms]![Flights]![cboDeparture] 
And [Forms]![Flights]![cboDeparture2]) 
And (TimeValue([Forms]![Flights]![cboDeparture])>[Forms]![Flights]![cboGreaterThanTi‌​me])
```

This is the code that I used for **Method 2:**

```
    Between (DateValue([Forms]![Flights]![cboDeparture])+#09:30:00#) 
And [Forms]![Flights]![cboDeparture2]
```

Comment: That was not what I wrote - and comboboxes return text, not date values.

Comment: The code i entered above is the original code i used. It is not the code that you gave me. i tried your code by substituting my combo box controls for the date and time values. The code looked like this (Between [Forms]![Flights]![cboDeparture] And [Forms]![Flights]![cboDeparture2]) 
And (TimeValue([Forms]![Flights]![cboDeparture])>[Forms]![Flights]![cboGreaterThanTime])

Comment: sorry for the confusion. ive edited the main post again. please read it to see the formulas i used based on Gustavs code.Thanks

Comment: See my answer where text are converted to date/time values.

Comment: How should i write it seeing as im referencing combo box controls.

Comment: My Departure1 and Departure2 combo boxes are formatted as dd/mm/yyyy and the GreaterThanTime combo box is formatted as hh:mm. When I just use the departure combos to find a date between those dates the formula works perfectly so i dont understand when you say that combos dont return date values

Comment: What have i entered incorrectly in  my two code examples in the main post. I followed your examples in both

Comment: Text is text and not date values. What you see in the combobox is just text that looks like a formatted date. Thus, follow my answer carefully, not partly.

Comment: I tried using the latest version you provided for combo boxes. i copied and pasted the code into the query grid and ran the query. Instead of my form opening up I got an Access Dialog box which asked me for parameters.

Comment: Then something is spelled incorrectly. You have four names for comboboxes but use three only.

Comment: i tried it again by copy and paste, I ran the query and the form opened. However the records are blank. I then checked the records in the table and there are two flights with a depearture time later than 09:30(entered in combobox) and the rest are earlier.

Comment: Apologies. When I said Departure1 earlier I made a mistake. I have three combos. they are cboDeparture,cboDeparture2 and cboGreaterThanTime.

Comment: I've edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks for editing but it doesnt work. I copied and pasted and ran the query and im still getting an Access Dialog box asking for parameters. Ive also noticed that after closing and reopening the query the TimeValue part of the expression was removed and placed in its own column in the design grid.

Comment: The code that worked best was the second option that you wrote. There must be a reason that it returned earlier flights as well as later flights than the given time.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
(Between [Date1] And [Date2]) And (TimeValue([Date1]) > #09:30#)
```

or:

```
Between (DateValue([Date1]) + #09:30#) And [Date2]
```

With comboboxes perhaps:

```
Between DateValue([Forms]![Flights]![cboDeparture]) And DateValue([Forms]![Flights]![cboDeparture2])
And
TimeValue([Forms]![Flights]![cboDeparture]) > TimeValue([Forms]![Flights]![cboGreaterThanTime])
```

Comment: Thanks,I have tried the fiorst method and its not working. Im going to try the second method now. Ill post back

Comment: Ive tried the second method and its not working either. The expression builder allows me to write up both expressions as you provided and doesnt give any error messages but both formulas are returning times before 09:30 as well as after 09:30.

Comment: The formula i quoted above is a simpler way of writing the formula below. The formula below references controls in a form and is the exact formula that I have in the expression builder:

(Between [Forms]![Flights]![cboDeparture1]
And
[Forms]![Flights]![cboDeparture2])
And
(TimeValue([Forms]![Flights]![cboDeparture1])>[Forms]![Flights]![cboGreaterThanTime])

Comment: That may be because your code doesn't follow mine. There are several differences.

Comment: do i have to guess. could u not just tell me what the differences are

Comment: Yes you will. It is two lines of simple and straight code. You really should be able to proofread this.